# tellg() for const reference object. "Copying" fstream object

Tags: c++

I'm writing a class for working with text files. I would like to "copy" ifstream-object properties. The code below shows how I'm doing it. I have a problem with a function  **w.m_fin.tellg()**:

- error C2662: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::tellg' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const std::ifstream' to 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &'

I want to set a file position in the destination object as in the source.
If I make the argument non-const  [ Word(Word& w) ] all is OK. But I don't want to make it non-const. What should I do in order to solve this problem?

Thank you

```
class Word
{
private:
    std::ifstream m_fin;
    std::string m_in_filename;

public:

    Word(const Word& w):  m_in_filename( w.m_in_filename ) 
    {
        m_fin(m_in_filename);
        m_fin.copyfmt( w.m_fin );                                  
        m_fin.clear( w.m_fin.rdstate() );
        m_fin.seekg( w.m_fin.tellg() );//here I get an error
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `w`? I don't see it's declared somewhere

Comment: @soon: Presumably `w` is supposed to be the same as `prep`. @DFooz: Please always post real code that demonstrates your problem. It's great that you edited your code for posting here, but when you do that, you need to make sure that the edited version still demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @ruakh, you are right. Sorry. Fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since b`tellg` (by potentially setting `fail` status)  changes the state of the  stream (as does seek and any form of read or write operation of course), you can't do that on a `const` object. However, I expect you could, if you wanted to solve it that way, declare `m_fin` as `mutable`, which means the compiler allows it to be changed even for `const` object.